# need a Regular expression to split string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Regular expression that allows me to split the following string in c#:

> Product Name : product name some text adfasd asdfas   Quantity : 1 
>   Base Price : 999.00
>
> Vendor Product ID : text-text-text-text

to get this result

```
text
text
text
text
```

the "-" is repeated from 2 to 5 times

note : this pattern is part of big pattern so i cannot use string.split

i try this `(-?(.+?)?-?(.+?)?-?(.+?)?)\s`

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: yes (-?(.+?)?-?(.+?)?-?(.+?)?)\s

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you could probably just do `@".* Vendor Product ID : (.*-){1,4}(.*)"` (not sure on this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `([a-zA-Z]+)(?:-([a-zA-Z]+)){0,3}`